# How to create a white-list for usb devices using udev rules?

Tags: usb, blocking, udev, whitelist

I'm trying to create a white-list using udev rules for USB devices on my CentOS machine however i get inconsistent results.

I tried blocking one device on a specific USB port using: 'echo 0/1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/authorized' and setting ATTR{authorized}="0/1" which worked fine, however when i try to block/allow all other devices, it seems to ignore the opposite rule. I tried adding the "last_rule" option as well, but no gain.

My rule is placed in /etc/udev/rules.d/01-usb-block.rules:

```
ACTION    != "add", GOTO = "usblist_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM == "usb", GOTO = "usblist_usb_rules"
GOTO="usblist_rules_end"

LABEL="usblist_usb_rules"

# Enable G20
ATTR{idVendor}=="0525", GOTO="usblist_rules_end"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0525", GOTO="usblist_rules_end"

# Enable USB to serial hub
ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", GOTO="usblist_rules_end"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", GOTO="usblist_rules_end"

# Enable linux foundation 3.0 root hub
ATTR{idVendor}=="1d6b", ATTR{idProduct}=="0003", GOTO="usblist_rules_end"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003", GOTO="usblist_rules_end"

# Enable linux foundation 2.0 root hub
ATTR{idVendor}=="1d6b", ATTR{idProduct}=="0002", GOTO="usblist_rules_end"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002", GOTO="usblist_rules_end"

# Disable all other devices
ATTR{authorized}="0"
ATTRS{authorized}="0"

LABEL="usblist_rules_end"
EOF
```

When i connect a USB mouse or keyboard it seems that "authorized" attributed remains the same when i use udevadm info on the connected port. Any suggestions?